# PHP Resumable Download

Tags: php, download, resume-download

I found this function on the internet:

```
function download_file($file,$ctype, $is_resume=TRUE)
{
    //First, see if the file exists
    if (!is_file($file))
    {
        die("<b>404 File not found!</b>");
    }
    //Gather relevent info about file
    $size = filesize($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($file);
    //workaround for IE filename bug with multiple periods / multiple dots in filename
    //that adds square brackets to filename - eg. setup.abc.exe becomes setup[1].abc.exe
    $filename = (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) ?
        preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileinfo['basename'], substr_count($fileinfo['basename'], '.') - 1) :
        $fileinfo['basename'];
    //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
    if($is_resume && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {
        list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
        {
            //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
            //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
            list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
    }
    //figure out download piece from range (if set)
    list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);
    //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
    //also check for invalid ranges.
    $seek_end = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($size - 1));
    $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);
    //add headers if resumable
    if ($is_resume)
    {
        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        }
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$size);
    }
    //headers for IE Bugs (is this necessary?)
    //header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
    //header("Pragma: public");
    header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
    //open the file
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    //seek to start of missing part
    fseek($fp, $seek_start);
    //start buffered download
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        //reset time limit for big files
        set_time_limit(0);
        print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

The download is working, but when I use Download Manager (IDM Etc.) and I want to pause the download to continue it later, I can't. This function is supposed to allow that (look at the `Content-Range` header), but for some reason, it does not work.

Does anyone know why? And how do I fix it?

I've tried a lot of functions that I found on the internet, but nothing works properly.

Answer (score 1):

@see https://github.com/audith/Persephone/blob/master/sources/handlers/static.php - starting from Line 658 for an example.

Suffice to say, resumable downloading requires correct HTTP header handling, specifically 'Connection: close' one wherever necessary.